# Unity editor PropertyDrawer custom button

Tags: unity

I has a PropertyDrawer, everything goes fine, except one feature: I can't figure out how to add button and I use checkbox instead

[image: Screenshot]

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;

[CustomPropertyDrawer (typeof (InteractiveObject))]
class InteractiveObjectPropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer {

public override void OnGUI (Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label) {

    EditorGUI.BeginProperty (position, label, property);
    position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel (position, GUIUtility.GetControlID (FocusType.Passive), label);
    var indent = EditorGUI.indentLevel;
    EditorGUI.indentLevel = 0;
    Rect colorRect = new Rect (position.x, position.y, 40, position.height);
    Rect unitRect = new Rect (position.x + 50, position.y, 90, position.height);
    Rect nameRect = new Rect (position.x + 150, position.y, position.width - 150, position.height);

    EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
    EditorGUI.PropertyField (colorRect, property.FindPropertyRelative ("show"), GUIContent.none);
    if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck() ) {
        RenderSettings.skybox.SetColor("_highlight", property.FindPropertyRelative ("id").colorValue);
    }

    EditorGUI.PropertyField (unitRect, property.FindPropertyRelative ("name"), GUIContent.none);
    EditorGUI.PropertyField (nameRect, property.FindPropertyRelative ("name"), GUIContent.none);
    EditorGUI.indentLevel = indent;
    EditorGUI.EndProperty ();
}
}
```

How I can add button there?

Comment: Presumably you tried [GUILayout.Button as recommended here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/adding-buttons-custom-inspector)? What went wrong?

Comment: @DMGregory yes, in this case buttons appear under all listed items...

Comment: GUILayout is not supported on PropertyDrawers. You need to just use the GUI class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found how to add button to PropertyDrawer [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html)

code:

```
 if (GUI.Button(text, "show")) {
     ...
 }
```

and result:

[image]

Comment: youre documentation link looks wrong. Do you mean this?  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html

Comment: @Evorlor thank you, it is a copy/paste problem